# Prove that $\gcd[(x^2 + 7 y^2), (5 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 - 7 y^4)]=1$ if $x,y$ are coprime integers of opposite parity where $x$ is not divisible by 7.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y$ be coprime integers of opposite parity, show that if $x$ is not divisible by 7, then $$\gcd[(x^2 + 7 y^2), (5 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 - 7 y^4)]=1$$
I am not sure where to begin. Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is a prime $p$ which divde both expressions. So $$x^2\equiv _p -7y^2$$ and

$$5x^4 \equiv _p 14x^2y^2+7y^4$$ then $$ 5\cdot 49y^4 \equiv _p -2\cdot 49y^4+7y^4$$ so $ p\mid 3\cdot 16\cdot 7 y^4$.

- If $p\mid y$ then $p\mid x^2$ a contradiction.
- If $p\mid 7$ then $p=7$ and $7\mid x$. A contradiction.
- If $p\mid 3$ then $p=3$ and $3\mid x^2+y^2$. Since $p\equiv _4 3$ we have $p\mid x$ and $p\mid y$. A contradiction.
- If $p\mid 16$ then $p=2$ and $2\mid x^2+y^2$ so $x,y$ have the same parity. A contradiction.

So no such prime.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+7y^2\equiv x+y\equiv 0+1\ \text{or }\ 1+0\equiv 1 \pmod 2\tag 1$$
and
$$x^2+7y^2\equiv x^2+y^2\equiv 1\ \text{or }\ 2 \pmod 3\tag2$$
because neither $x^2$ and $y^2$ is equivalent to $2$ and both can't be $\equiv 0\pmod 3.$

$$\gcd(x^2 + 7 y^2, 5 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 - 7 y^4)\tag 3$$
$$=\gcd(x^2 + 7 y^2, 5 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 - 7 y^4)$$
$$=\gcd(x^2 + 7 y^2, 49 x^2 y^2 + 7 y^4)$$
$$=\gcd(x^2 + 7 y^2, 48 x^2 y^2 )$$
$$=\gcd(x^2 + 7 y^2, x^2 y^2 ),$$
because, by (1) and (2), neither $2$ nor $3$ divides
the left argument.  Finally, (3) equals
$$\gcd(x^2 + 7 y^2, 7y^4 )\tag 4$$
Since any prime dividing $y$ does not divide $x,$ we conclude from (4) that $$\gcd(x^2 + 7 y^2, 5 x^4 - 14 x^2 y^2 - 7 y^4)=1.$$

• I used that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b+ka).$

Comment: It would help to explicitly explain the methods you used in the gcd calculations in $(3)$ since likely they are not clear to many readers.

Comment: Your pontification is noted. If any reader cannot repeat any of
my calculations (using the one rule that I gave), please leave a comment so that I can help you.

Comment: I'll explain it then. The first gcd reduction step eliminates the $x^4$ term in the 2nd gcd arg by subtracting $5x^2(x^2+7y^2)\,$ (then negating), and the 2nd step eliminates the $y^4$ term by subtracting $y^2(x^2+7y^2).\,$ Equivalently the 2nd arg $= (x^2+7y^2)(5x^2-y^2) - 48x^2y^2\equiv -48x^2y^2\pmod{\!x^2+7y^2}.\,$ As usual it is easier to deduce this with modular arithmetic, similar to that in Aqua's answer.

Comment: Bill, A student will absorb a new technique by doing her own calulations. For another question of the same kind, she must figure out what multiplier to use in applying my rule. I want real students to learn this technique and ask me if they need help. You did okay, but my answer was not aimed at you.